# Return contents of cell with specific length in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am in a situation where I need to find the first cell in a range that has the max length of all cells in the range, and return its contents.

I have used MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(LEN({A:A}))) to find the cell with the largest length of characters, which in my specific case, is 14 characters long, but I need to go the next step, and return the contents of that cell.

I would just go CELL("contents", MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(LEN({A:A})))), but that isn't the reference of the cell with the highest value, that is just the number 14.

There can be multiple cells in a range with a 14-character length, so I only need the first instance of it.

I must be so very close to a solution, but just can't quite get there,
I thank you in advance for looking into this,
Daniel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=QUERY(FILTER(A:A,len(A:A)=14),"limit 1")
```

Comment: Ahh yes, this totally makes sense. If you for sure know the length of the cell's contents, this is perfect. This could also be slightly modified to pick out the max length cell, by using MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(LEN({A:A}))) instead of LEN(A:A) = 14.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved with the addition of checking the index: CELL("contents",INDEX(F22:F25,MATCH(MAX(LEN(F22:F25)),LEN(F22:F25),0)))

Thanks to Gareth Haage for personally messaging me about the solution.